# Gridview won't display image buttons

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to set up a grid view that displays a grid of image buttons. I have also have a drag layer set up so that you should be able to click and drag the buttons to different locations. My problem is that the grid view won't display the image buttons.
Here are the two xml files that set up the layout. main.xml and row_grid.xml are in res/layout.

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edu.purdue.app.DragLayer
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drag_layer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/button_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="@integer/num_columns"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="@color/light_gray"
      />

    </edu.purdue.app.DragLayer>
```

row_grid.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/MapButton"
        android:layout_width="104dp"
        android:layout_height="92dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageButton>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main Activity:

```
public class PurdueAppActivity extends Activity implements View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnClickListener,
    View.OnTouchListener{
        public static final boolean Debugging = false;
        DragController mDragController;   // Object that handles a drag-drop sequence. It intersacts with DragSource and DropTarget objects.
        DragLayer mDragLayer;             // The ViewGroup within which an object can be dragged.

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.button_grid_view);
            gridView.setAdapter (new ImageButtonCellAdapter(this,R.layout.row_grid));
            // gridView.setOnItemClickListener (this);
            mDragController = new DragController(this);
            mDragLayer = (DragLayer) findViewById(R.id.drag_layer);
            mDragLayer.setDragController (mDragController);
            mDragLayer.setGridView (gridView);
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return startDrag (v);
        }

        public boolean startDrag (View v)
        {
            DragSource dragSource = (DragSource) v;

            // We are starting a drag. Let the DragController handle it.
            mDragController.startDrag (v, dragSource, dragSource, DragController.DRAG_ACTION_MOVE);

            return true;
        }

    }
```

Lastly, here is the adapter class' getView() method that is supposed to set it up:

```
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    mParentView = parent;

    ImageButtonCell v = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        // If it's not recycled, create a new ImageCell.
        v = new ImageButtonCell (mContext);
        v.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        v.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        v.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

    } else {
        v = (ImageButtonCell) convertView;
    }

    v.mCellNumber = position;
    v.mGrid = (GridView) mParentView;
    v.mEmpty = true;
//    v.setBackgroundResource (R.color.drop_target_enabled);
    v.setBackgroundResource (R.color.light_gray);

    //v.mGrid.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (true);

    //v.setImageResource (R.drawable.hello);

    // Set up to relay events to the activity.
    // The activity decides which events trigger drag operations.
    // Activities like the Android Launcher require a long click to get a drag operation started.
    v.setOnTouchListener ((View.OnTouchListener) mContext);
    v.setOnClickListener ((View.OnClickListener) mContext);
    v.setOnLongClickListener ((View.OnLongClickListener) mContext);

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_grid, null);
    }

    ImageButton imagebtn = (ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.MapButton);
    //do something on imagebtn
    return v;
}
```

Comment: If I wanted to add more than one button, I'm assuming I can just add them using the same strategy for MapButton you posted correct?  And the grid view will place all of them in its layout?